# Google Analytics event based goal conversion rate

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, conversions, reporting, event-tracking

I use Google Universal Analytics and track many events on my website.

I have defined an **event based goal**, based on the 'user signed in' event.

When looking at the reports, I figured that the goal conversion rate is calculated as:

```
(number of 'user signed in' events) / (total number of unique events)
```

1. Is that really the way the rate is calculated? Since I have many unrelated events on my site, the conversion rate is meaningless
2. How exactly are unique events calculated?
3. What I'm trying to track is the number of unique visits in which the user signed in. Is there a proper way to track it (preferably without creating fake pageviews)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion rate for a defined date range is calculated by this formula, where all numbers are taken for a given date range:

*(number of 'user signed in' events) / (number of sessions)*

This every conversion's rate is tracked separately, not related to other ones.

Creating this event will let you track what you want, it seems you've got confused because you misunderstood the formula.

Comment: Thank you. After digging some more, it seems to be the case. What got me confused is that the value of unique events is exactly the same as the number of sessions. But apparently this is a documented (bug?) behaviour of GA.